# File not getting copied from script

Tags: java, javascript, javafx

I have built the msi installer for my javafx application using the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/self-contained-packaging.htm) and it works well. But in my application I need to start some java process for which I need access to java.exe. And the installer runtime does not provide `java.exe`

From this [tutorial](https://blogs.oracle.com/talkingjavadeployment/entry/native_packaging_cookbook_using_drop) I wrote the below script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<package> 
<job id="postImage"> 
<script language="JScript"> 
<![CDATA[ 
var oFSO = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"); 
var oFolder = oFSO.getFolder("."); 
var from = "C:
Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_21\\bin
java.exe"; 
var to = oFolder.path + "\\Pina\\runtime\\bin"; 
if (!oFSO.FolderExists(to)) { 
oFSO.CreateFolder(to); 
} 
oFSO.CopyFile(from, to); 
]]> 
</script> 
</job>
```

But I do not see it getting copied. Even after changing to `var to = oFolder.path + "\\Pina";` to check if it actually copies yields no results. 
I can see the scipt being run as verbose prints:

> Using custom package resource [script to run after application image is populated] (loaded from package/windows/Pina-post-image.wsf on class path)

What am I dong it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the user used for running the script, has right permission to the target 
directory.

Comment: Actually I have observed, that it does copy it in temporary files (to me it copied at C:\Users\Jatin\AppData\Local\Temp\build3489358754829980218.fxbundler\images\win-msi\Pina\runtime\jre\bin) but not to the actual installer